# attach file as multipart/form-data content-type - Laravel

Tags: php, multipartform-data

I am using FreshDesk API as a ticketing system. When trying to send an attachment, it was stated that it should be sent as multipart/form-data content-type. Could someone explain how this is done?!
How I am sending attachments:

```
$json = json_encode(
          array(
                "helpdesk_note" => array(
                "body" => Input::get('reply'),
                "user_id" => $requester_id,
                "attachments" => Input::get('photo'),
                "private" => true
            )
        )
      );
```

Comment: U mean this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're querying the API but in case you're using CURL, just set the appropriate header:

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURL_HTTPHEADER , "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" );
```

Personally I would recommend [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which has a clean and straightforward API. 
In Guzzle you can modify your headers in a more OO-Way. There are several ways to accomplish your task. On possible approach could be:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'https://url.com/to/post/to');
$request->setHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
// Set the data you need to

$response = $client->send($request);
var_dump($response);
```

Guzzle btw, is a piece of cake to integrate with Laravel. Just require it in your `composer.json` and you're good to go!